# how to update dual boot windows 7 / ubuntu 13.04 to 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I currently have ubuntu 13.04 installed, dual boot with Windows 7

I am unsure of how to do a clean install of ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot with windows 7 (i dont mind loosing the entire ubuntu/linux partitions for a clean install)

any suggestions or guidance would be most welcome

Thank you

EDIT:- thank you all (I am editing/ to update this question as suggested clayton), I need to delete another partition, I tried to install 12.04 LTS and need to remove that

Ideally, I would like to do a clean install of all and remove ubuntu completely, than a fresh install of 14.04 (and this time with a more space allocated) Apologies I did not mention this earlier

Comment: Read through this link from [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes) and then edit your question if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Oh, well the edit changes my answer, but the update would still be more ideal

Answer (score 2):

During the system setup, there is an option for "something else" when partitioning. If you look into this, you can format the partition for Ubuntu 13.04 and mark it to install Ubuntu 14.04. This will leave your Windows 7 partition untouched.

Comment: I suggest that you change clean to format to improve clarity

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I managed to do something similar - i went into windows and formatted all the ubuntu partitions (this resulted in loosing GRUB/MBR issues) ; so I then carried out an install with "Install ubuntu alongside other OS..." This cleaned out Grub and installed fresh copy. thanks for all your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Simple! You can just update from your Ubuntu 13.04 up to 14.04! It takes a while, but what you do is go to your software updater, and once you have all your updates installed, chose to upgrade to 13.10, then to 14.04! It's that easy and doesn't require a full reinstall of the system.

Comment: A full reinstall would be quicker than 2 upgrades....

Comment: But a full reinstall would take away all your data and would make you have to put your entire home drive and stick it on a USB, which could take a little while and might result in you buying a rather large USB.

Comment: " (i dont mind loosing the entire ubuntu/linux partitions for a clean install)" If this is not accurate please change the question.

Comment: Thanks - i did thinkabot doing the updates, but really wanted a clean install if possible - so went with deleting the partitions and clean install

Comment: Sounds good! Enjoy 14.04 Trusty Tarh!

Answer (score 0):

In the application menu for gnome search "update manager" and proceed to update. You don't need to delete your current file system.